# Snapping to faces problem, they snap to the inside of the item instead of the outside

Tags: snapping

I'm trying to make a simple blade but I have a problem when trying to snap spikes onto my blade. They snap to the inside of the item instead of the outside.

Any ideas what could be the problem here? Again I'm fresh to Blender but I could not find a solution to this on my own I tried rotating the object but with no success.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try rotating it in edit mode. If that doesn't work can you upload the Blend file?

Comment: I solved thanks to my friend below, just a case of miss matched normals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a problem of the normals being facing inside the mesh. Select all the faces and recalculate normals (provided all normals are facing inside). Then try snapping to the face.

The operator for recalculating normals is under the view header mesh menu. The hotkey is also displayed in the menu items.

Mesh -> Normals -> Recalculate Inside/Outside and Flip Normals

In case some of the faces only have normals facing inside, then select those faces and flip the normals.

Comment: Thank you it worked. I had to recalculate the insides (ctrl shift n I believe it was) and i worked :)

Comment: @Matt Great! Also, for debugging "normal" related problems, while in the edit mode for meshes you can visualize them (vertex, face normals) from the Properties Panel (N key in 3D view editor)